# In Gmail, search for emails containing one specific label and any other label

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-search

Is it possible in Gmail to search for emails containing one specific label (i.e. New York), and any other label available.  In other words, I need to exclude emails that contain only one label.

Comment: There's no way AFAIK that you can retrieve the number of labels on a given email. And when you say "only one label", are you nesting labels (e.g. a label 'friends/nyc') ?

Comment: in this case, yes, NYC is a nested label-- a child of the 'city' tree.  I can't believe GMail doesn't have this feature.